# Particle collision detection on cloned objects not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to spawn several circles on the screen as game objects that float around randomly. To do this I have a prefab that I am instantiating x number of times in a script attached to a main game object. Then I have a 2nd script attached to the prefab to control the random movement. I added a Particle System to the prefab, so that each spawned clone has particles emitting from its edges. I want to know if one object's particles collide with anything, be it another cloned object, a wall, etc. But my OnParticleCollision (in the movement script attached to the prefab) is not logging anything to the console, it seems to not detect particle collisions at all. Maybe I'm not understanding the bigger concept and instantiating multiple instances of the same prefab with a particle system is not the best approach? Or am I making a more obvious minor mistake?

Things I have tried based on other questions:

- Send collision messages IS checked
- I do not have any colliders marked as triggers
- I verified the visual bounds look correct in Scene View
- Collision between cloned game objects themselves work fine, it's only the Particle Collisions not working.

My script attached to the prefab:

```
public class BubbleMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(min, max);
        ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        ps.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 0);
        ps.Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
     
    }

    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject col){
        Debug.Log("Collision Particle: " + col);
    }
    
}
```

Images of my prefab inspector settings for Rigidbody2D, Circle Collider, and Particle System:
[image: RigidBody2D]
[image: CircleCollider2D]
[image: ParticleSystem1]
[image: ParticleSystem2]
[image: ParticleSystem3]
[image: ParticleSystem4]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I see the rigidbody is not defined in the inspector for the BubbleMove script.